# Bittrex API - PHP JSON Decode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a problem with getting the balances of my bittrex account:

```
$apikey='Removed';
$apisecret='Removed';
$nonce=time();
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalances?apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);

$data=file_get_contents( $execResult );
$json=json_decode( $data );

$result=$json->result;
foreach( $result as $i => $object ){
    echo $object->Balance,'<br />';
}
```

It only delivers the following JSON:

```
  {
"success":true,
"message":"",
"result":[
{
"Currency":"ADA",
"Balance":1800.00000000,
"Available":1800.00000000,
"Pending":0.00000000,
"CryptoAddress":null
},
{
"Currency":"ARK",
"Balance":0.00000000,
"Available":0.00000000,
"Pending":0.00000000,
"CryptoAddress":null
},
{
"Currency":"BTC",
"Balance":0.00007135,
"Available":0.00007135,
"Pending":0.00000000,
"CryptoAddress":"XXX"
}   
]
}
```

Reading one dimensional data, it works fine:

```
    $btrxprice ="https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-ETH";
    $fgc = json_decode(file_get_contents($btrxprice), true);                                                
    $bidprice = $fgc["result"]["Bid"];
```

Where is my problem? I try to get the balance of one ore the nth-coin

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Is the JSON not what you expected? Is the output of your program not what you expected? What do you want versus what's happening now?

Comment: I would like to print out the balance. I do not want the JSON, I need the values. Thanks!

Comment: And... does your code not do that?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I only get the JSON printed out from curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`. Without that, the response body isn't returned to you at all. Try this:

```
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($data);
```